# Following a path in Spritekit EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics

I have a simple Snake game where the head draws a UIBezier path. That part works fine:

```
func addLineToSnakePath(snakeHead: SnakeBodyUnit) {
    //add a new CGPoint to array
    activeSnakePathPoints.append(CGPoint(x: snakeHead.partX, y: snakeHead.partY))

    let index = activeSnakePathPoints.count-1

    if (index == 1) {
        path.moveToPoint(activeSnakePathPoints[index-1])
    }

    path.addLineToPoint(activeSnakePathPoints[index])
    shapeNode.path = path.CGPath
}
```

The path generates with swipes as the Head moves around the screen. Now I add a body unit to follow the UIBezier path and I get a bad access error.

```
 func addBodyPart() {
    let followBody = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 1.0)
    snakePart.runAction(followBody)
 }
```

Crash at:
0 SKCFollowPath::cpp_willStartWithTargetAtTime(SKCNode*, double)

Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I would rather strengthen my code this way:

```
func addLineToSnakePath(snakeHead: CGPoint) {
    let count = activeSnakePathPoints.count
    if count == 0  { return } // The snake don't have an head..
    //add a new CGPoint to array
    activeSnakePathPoints.append(CGPoint(x: snakeHead.x, y: snakeHead.y))
    guard count > 1 else {
        // There are only two element (the head point and the new point) so:
        path = UIBezierPath.init() 
        path.moveToPoint(activeSnakePathPoints[count-1])
        shapeNode.path = path.CGPath
        return
    }
    // There are some elements:
    path.addLineToPoint(activeSnakePathPoints[count-1])
    shapeNode.path = path.CGPath
}
```

Next, when you make the [followPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417798-followpath?language=objc) action I've seen you use `offset` value to true ( I don't know if this is wanted from you..):

> asOffset : If YES, the points in the path are relative offsets to the
>   node’s starting position. If NO, the points in the node are absolute
>   coordinate values.

In other words **true** means the path is relative from the sprite's starting position, **false** means absolute

Finally in the line:

```
snakePart.runAction(followBody)
```

I don't know what is `snakePart` but you use `shapeNode` in your function

**Update**:

Thinking about your crash, seems `snakePart` is not a valid SKNode (like when you try to use a sprite or shape without initialize itself)